# Silex form validation without translation

Tags: php, forms, frameworks, twig, silex

I'd like to use Silex's service providers just to build a simple contact form with validation but it seems to be only with translation service provider because when I render the view I have a Twig_Error_Syntax 'The filter "trans" does not exist', I guess it's because I have to customize(override) 'form_div_layout.html.twig' and remove trans filter ? I don't need translation.

I didn't implement validation yet.

Here's my code :

```php
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request ;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response ;

require_once __DIR__ . '/bootstrap.php' ;

$app = new Silex\Application() ;

require __DIR__ . '/../config/conf.php';

$app->register(new Silex\Provider\SymfonyBridgesServiceProvider(), array(
      'symfony_bridges.class_path' => __DIR__ . '/../vendor/symfony/src',
)) ;

$app->register(new Silex\Provider\HttpCacheServiceProvider(), array(
      'http_cache.cache_dir' => __DIR__ . '/../cache/',
)) ;

$app->register(new Silex\Provider\FormServiceProvider(), array(
      'form.class_path' => __DIR__ . '/../vendor/symfony/src'
)) ;

$app->register(new Silex\Provider\ValidatorServiceProvider(), array(
      'validator.class_path' => __DIR__ . '/../vendor/symfony/src',
)) ;

$app->register(new Silex\Provider\TwigServiceProvider(), array(
      'twig.path' => __DIR__ . '/../src/views/frontend/',
      'twig.class_path' => __DIR__ . '/../vendor/twig/lib',
      'twig.options' => array('cache' => $app['http_cache.cache_dir'] . 'twig.cache'),
)) ;

$app->get('/contact', function (Silex\Application $app) use ($navigation) {

       $form = $app['form.factory']->createBuilder('form')
               ->add('name', 'text')
               ->add('surname', 'text')
               ->add('email', 'email')
               ->add('message', 'textarea')
               ->getForm() ;

       $response = new Response() ;
       $page = $app['twig']->render('contact.html.twig', array('navigation' => $navigation, 'form' => $form->createView())) ;
       $response->setContent($page) ;
       return $response ;
    }) ;
```

and in the contact page :

```twig
<form class="form-horizontal" action="/contact" method="post">
 <fieldset class="control-group">
                <legend>Contact</legend>

                  {{ form_errors(form) }}
                  {{ form_row(form.name) }
                  {{ form_row(form.surname) }}
                  {{ form_row(form.email) }}
                  {{ form_row(form.message) }}

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Send</button>

 </fieldset>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to customize the form layout by removing trans filters

Comment: Could you provide an example of how to do this?

Comment: As it stands, this answer doesn't give enough of an explanation at all.

Answer (score 24):

Got the same problem and I was able to solve it by adding:

```
$app->register(new Silex\Provider\TranslationServiceProvider(), array(
    'translator.messages' => array(),
));
```

Comment: Just a note, I had to put this near the top of registering service providers as doing it after doctrine / twig / form / validator / asset caused problems. Do it near the top when creating your service providers and all should go well.

Answer (score 5):

Another way to do this would be to provide Twig with the filters...

```
function dummy_trans($str) {
    return $str;
}

$app['twig']->addFilter('trans*', new Twig_Filter_Function('dummy_trans'));
```

(N.B) the asterisk denotes a dynamic Twig filter, essentially a wildcard.

I've only tested this very briefly but seems to do the job.

Comment: +1, since this seems to be the only solution which is independent of "Silex". It can be further improved by using an anonymous function, e.g.: $viewEnvironment->addFilter(
    'trans*',
    new \Twig_Filter_Function(
        function($str) {
            return $str;
        }
    )
);

Comment: This doesn't work for choice form fields, i.e. the `transChoice` filter. Symfony's [IdentityTranslator](https://github.com/symfony/Translation/blob/2.3/IdentityTranslator.php#L73) shows that there's a little bit more work to do to return the correct identity translation for a list of translations.

Answer (score 2):

It is stated in the [Silex documentation](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/providers/form.html#registering):

> If you don't want to create your own form layout, it's fine: a default one will be used. But you will have to register the translation provider as the default form layout requires it.

So all you have to do, if you want to use the default layout, is the following:

```
$app->register(new Silex\Provider\TranslationServiceProvider());
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to bypass the translation errors by doing this:

```
$app = new Silex\Application();
$app['translator.messages'] = array();
```